# App to display Word/PowerPoint/PDF within a page

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for an application which could be embedded within a web page that would allow the viewing of uploaded PDFs, Word Documents, and PowerPoints. The more that it could support the better. One with some sort of API to dynamically embed the files.

`http://www.scribd.com/` looks promising but does anyone have experience using it, or a different one?

Comment: I _can't stand_ the scribd interface. If I had wanted something that "heavy," I'd have used Acrobat in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer).

You just append the URL of the document to the doc viewer URL, then throw it in an iframe or something. No API needed. Supports PDF, PPT, and TIFF.

Comment: Google Docs Viewer now supports over 15 different file types

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Box recently achieved embedding [Box.net](http://blog.box.net/2010/06/01/embed-box-net-files-anywhere-on-the-web/)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I wanted to be able to dynamically embed them. Not do something by hand.

Comment: google doc embed had issues with explorer 8 (maybe they fixed it by now).  So be warned...

Comment: Updated answer for embedding

Comment: @Tal Galili yea I updated the answer was trying to rollback a deleted answer instead of starting a new one

Answer (score 0):

For PDFs [try PDF2SWF](http://www.swftools.org/), it's a bit ugly and doesn't support the scroll wheel, but it works and is free. You also have to host it yourself, but that gives you more control and lets you embed files dynamically if you site set-up your site to do that.

They have [a demo of it here.](http://www.swftools.org/flash/paper5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Two that I like are:

1. http://www.slideshare.net/
2. http://www.docstoc.com/